# Why are there 2 methods for getindex?

Tags: julia

In the source code, I see 2 methods are implemented for getindex.

```
# T[x...] constructs Array{T,1}
function getindex(T::Type, vals...)
    a = Array(T,length(vals))
    @inbounds for i = 1:length(vals)
        a[i] = vals[i]
    end
    return a
end

function getindex(::Type{Any}, vals::ANY...)
    a = Array(Any,length(vals))
    @inbounds for i = 1:length(vals)
        a[i] = vals[i]
    end
    return a
end
```

Why is the second one required?  I have read the performance-tips, but in this case type of `a` is stable: always `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are both `getindex` methods that are used for creating arrays through syntax such as e.g.

```
Int[1,4,9]
```

(first method) and

```
Any[1,4.0,"9"]
```

(second method). The second one is not strictly required, but is an optimization to cut down on compiler time and resources.

The type signature `::ANY` (as opposed to `::Any`) instructs the compiler not to specialize on the actual types of those arguments, which makes sense in this case since there would be no performance gain. It makes sense to have this special case in place since arrays will likely be constructed with the `Any[...]` syntax using a wide range of type combinations.